# Prompt user for filepath to loop folder files

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of providing the file path in my code, I prompt the user to select the folder that contains data files in xlsx format, over which is looped via: `For Each wbFile In fldr.Files`.

I am getting error 424.

See the commented out lines in the code:

```
Sub getDataFromWbs()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("\\name_of_folder_to_get_files_from\")  'old code

'Dim FolderName As String      'fldr was previously, original code: FolderName
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    fldr = .SelectedItems(1)     'fldr was previously, original code: FolderName
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

i = "1"                        'set integer for loop over sheets
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files  'loop over data in prompted folder
```

Comment: in `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`  `.SelectedItems(1) ` returns a string. In order to use `fldr.Files` you have to use the  `fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` solution

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`, it is a very poor practice to just ignore errors, and get no information about them. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your modules to require variable declarations, such as for `fldr`.

Comment: Yes I understand, the above code was a quick solution I found and is going to be updated as soon as I had the code working. I just started getting into VBA, but learning quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick fix of your code:

```
Sub getDataFromWbs()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("\\name_of_folder_to_get_files_from\")  'old code

'Dim FolderName As String      'fldr was previously, original code: FolderName
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
  On Error Resume Next
  FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)     'fldr was previously, original code: FolderName
  Err.Clear
  On Error GoTo 0
End With

i = "1"                        'set integer for loop over sheets
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
For Each wbFile In fldr.Files  'loop over data in prompted folder
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was close, but missed on the second to last line.